# nestjs websockets connecting but cannot receive message

Tags: websocket, nestjs

I am having trouble setting up nestjs with websockets. From chrome dev tools I can establish a connection:

```
let socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
```

I'm able to set a breakpoint in the `handleConnection` method and the connection looks healthy:

```
WebSocket {url: 'ws://localhost:3000/', readyState: 1, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, …}
```

But when I send a message `socket.send('hello testing');`. the message is not received. Breakpoints set inside `handleMessage` are not hit.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Is the line

```
app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));
```

correct and necessary? I don't know why I don't see this line in some online examples but without it, I cannot establish a connection without it though.

`app.gateway.ts`:

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  OnGatewayInit,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  @WebSocketServer()
  private wss: Server;
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('AppGateway');

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    this.logger.log('Initialized!');
  }
  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('*')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, text: string): void {
    this.wss.emit('msgToClient', text);  // not hitting this line
  }
}
```

`main.ts`:

```
import { join } from 'path';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { WsAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-ws' //Add this line

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  app.enableCors();
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app)); // Add this line
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppGateway } from './app.gateway';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [AppGateway],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if your socket client connect success with nest gateway or not

```js
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
socket.onopen = function() {
  console.log('Connected');
  socket.send(
    JSON.stringify({
      event: 'events',
      data: 'test',
    }),
  );
  socket.onmessage = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  };
};
```

view full example of nestjs websocket gateway on https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/16-gateways-ws

anyway: if you use SubscribeMessage decorator, you must follow nestjs format message. It is an Dto like

```
{event: string, data: any, error?: any, id?: string }
```

then event will match with SubscribeMessage